# Is it possible to change the "temperature" parameter of ChatGPT chats?

Tags: chatgpt, prompt-design

The OpenAI API has the possibility to set the temperature parameter (e.g. see [this](https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart/adjust-your-settings)).

Is it also possible to influence the temperature parameter of chats in the ChatGPT web UI?

I tried setting it in "Custom instructions" (->"Please use temperature 0.00"), but it seems not to work.

Comment: A possible follow-up question might be what could be an effective way to write a custom instruction that has a similar effect to changing the temperature parameter. Still, it would be convenient to provide context for posting a good question like this. Do you have a specific use case to post a question like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the "temperature" parameter of ChatGPT chats?

Not possible on https://chat.openai.com/. However, on https://platform.openai.com/playground one may change the temperature:

[image]

One may also change the temperature in the [Azure playground](https://portal.azure.com/):

[image]